# amazon glue execute scripts located on s3bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have created a python script and uploaded in S3 bucket,
Now I have created a spark glue job and set the script file path and trying to execute. but not working...

Why I am trying like this rather than writing script in glue script tab,

I have a script which will run for multiple clients depending on the client provided as  argument.

I don't want to create multiple job and put the script there, as if I need to change anything I need to update every scripts.

But If I am able to run it from S3 file, I can simply change script file and upload on S3.

Can someone please suggest what approach should I take..

Thanks

Comment: Why not simplify and use one glue job with one python script that checks for the "client" argument. You can use if-else at least or use the Strategy Pattern.